# m2eclipse search only searches local repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have m2eclipse installed in Springsource Tool Suite.  I have an installation of Maven 3.0.3 that I pointed m2eclipse to.  When I try to search for new artifacts - using Maven > Add Dependency, it seems to only show results from my local repository.  If I manually enter a new dependency in my POM, eclipse will resolve it (pull it into my project's classpath).  For some reason, only search does not work.  I know there are a lot of similar posts about this topic but none of those fixed my problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution:

http://paulbunting.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/spring-tool-suite-sts-m2eclipse-add-dependency-not-working/